# Files without changes after merge

Tags: svn, merge

I have some changes in branch. For merge I use tortoise. Everything is ok except there are a lot of file that doesn't change 
http://my.jetscreenshot.com/22879/20140218-9ivr-88kb.jpg

What can be reason for this? and How can I avoid it?

Comment: Goddam! There is `svn st` of WC after merge& There is `svn diff` of nodes before merge? You has shown **nothing relevant**, and we aren't sensitives here

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was silly question.
Anyway in my case solution was:
set "Ignore ancestry" and "Ignore line endings" during merging:

http://my.jetscreenshot.com/22879/20140218-ukun-36kb.jpg